# How to start GNU Octave with GUI through Cygwin from a desktop icon?

Tags: windows, batch-file, user-interface, cygwin, octave

Since GNU Octave comes wit a GUI since versions 3.8.0, I thought I should check it out.

So since I run Windows and could only find Octave 3.8 for Cygwin, I installed Cygwin and the packages `octave`, `xinit`, `xlaunch` and `gnuplot` (according to [this page](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Octave-3-8-1-on-Cygwin-Packages-td4664258.html), but I don't know if all those packages are needed).

Then, when trying to start Octave with the GUI from Cygwin with `octave --force-gui`, I initially got the error message

```
octave: X11 DISPLAY environment variable not set
```

and Octave would start in console mode. So I found [this page](http://petpari.blogspot.se/2013/04/octave-gnuplot-using-cygwins-x-server.html), which told me to run

```
echo "export DISPLAY=:0.0" >>~/.bash_profile
```

from Cygwin, to permanently get rid of the error message, which worked. However, then I instead got this error message:

```
octave: unable to open X11 DISPLAY
```

The same page also said that you have to run the X Server by going to Start -> Cygwin-X -> XWin Server. That worked, but since I don't want the xterm terminal to start since it is not needed, I found [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/435768/how-do-i-prevent-cygwins-xwin-server-automatically-starting-xterm) which told me to run

```
touch ~/.startxwinrc
```

from Cygwin to create an empty `.startxwinrc` file, to prevent the xtrem terminal from starting by default, which worked. The same page also mentioned that the X Server can be started directly from Cygwin with the command `startxwin`.

So, now I can start Octave with the GUI from Cygwin, simply by running

```
startxwin
octave --force-gui
```

However, I would like to just be able to double click on a desktop icon to get everything up and running.

**So, to my question:** *Can I somehow put this in a script file, which when I run it, will be opened in Cygwin so that the commands in the script file will be run in Cygwin? And is there some way to automatically close the X Server after Octave has terminated?* I've tried writing a file `octave.bat`, which starts Cygwin and gives a second batch file as argument, which in turn contains the commands I want to execute. But when I run the first script, I just get bombarded with command prompts (not Cygwin prompts), and the all say

```
'startxwin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Why is the second script not opened in Cygwin, and how can I achieve what I want as simply as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please grab Octave from here: http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/

The installer should configure everything for you.

GNU Octave offers now Windows binary itself. Go to ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/

Comment: I have installed using GNU octave using make install command. Now, script editor is not opening. This is only bug I have.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'startxwin /bin/octave --force-gui'
```

in your windows batch file (please adapt the Cygwin path to your settings). That worked fine for me.

The call

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "startxwin /bin/octave --force-gui"
```

did open Octave as desired but the GUI seemed to have response issues to the keyboard and froze after clicking into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any of the those commands installed with my Cygwin installation, so I can't test this by trying using the following an `.bat` file on your desktop:

```
 c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "startxwin octave --force-gui"
```

Replace `c:\cygwin` with the directory where you installed Cygwin.

If this leaves a console window on the screen try doing:

```
 c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "run startxwin octave --force-gui"
```

Comment: Isn't a semicolon missing after `startxwin`? Anyway, when I try these scripts, I just get a console window flashing for a fraction of a second. If I add a semicolon after `startxwin`, I get the Octave GUI running, but also just for a fraction of a second, then it is closed together with the console window. Adding `run` to the beginning of the string doesn't seem to have any effect in any case.

Comment: The semicolon isn't missing, `startxwin` will launch the command given as an argument after starting X, just like how it started `xterm`. Try adding the line `pause`, on a separate line, at the end of the batch script. That will keep the console window open long for you to read any error messages.

Comment: I don't get any error message. This is all I get: `$C:\Program1\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "startxwin octave --force-gui"`
(two blank lines)
`$pause`
`Press any key to continue . . .`, and Octave is not loaded.

Comment: Hmm... no idea then. Sorry.